# Number of long equation not below but above it

Tags: math-mode, numbering, align

Is there a way to display the number of a long equation (which usually appears below it if place is missing) above the equation?

That is, instead of what would appear if you compile the code below and looks like

> ...as the following equation shows
>
> Long equation output
>
> `[space space below it]`  (eq. number)

I'd like TeX to display

> ...as the following equation shows
>
> `[space space above eq.]`  (eq. number)
>
> Long equation output

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

...as the following equation shows
\begin{align}
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make sure that equation and its number fit into a single line instead? Could you please also make your example a bit closer to real life,since `blabla...` isn't actual math?

Comment: Probably you can achive the desired output using the `\raisetag` command from the `amsmath` package. `\raisetag{2\normalbaselineskip}` for example places the equation  number as shown in the following screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOKqQ.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\raisetag` command from the `amsmath` package might help to position th tag above the equation instead of below. Depending on the actual contents of the `align` environment the length might have to be adjusted accordingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

...as the following equation shows
\begin{align}
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
\raisetag{2\normalbaselineskip}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I approved your answer :-)